# testing method within react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

i am trying to test a react class method with enzyme. The method should handle change on an input and set the state. I am getting an error 'Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

component.js

```
class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        ...
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    ...

    return(
        ...
        <TextField name='username' onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
```

test.js

```
it('handles change', () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(LoginPage.prototype, 'handleChange');
    const _wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage />);

    spy({
            event: {
                target: {
                    name: 'username',
                    value: 'username'
                }
            }
        }
    );

    expect(_wrapper.state().username).to.equal('username');
})
```

});

Comment: And if you try this `<TextField name='username' onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />` ,btw, where is your render method?

Comment: I get `TypeError: Attempted to wrap handleChange which is already wrapped` even though i run restore() on the spy and the end of the test. I would prefer not to alter the component to make the test work when it is legitamet code. I cut out some of the code, which the `...` represent, so the renders there and the component renders fine

Comment: So your component is actually working. You just have the problem when integrating the tests. Right?

Comment: That's right.  Can't work out if it's what's being passed in that's the issue or that I need to mock out the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer, just notice that there are some other ways to write your component that would make it easier to write those tests (and using spies/stubs better). For example, you can pass "onChange" prop to component, and use that prop.

So, answering it, you are calling a function that isn't "binded" to anything. Your `this` (inside the spy you created) is `undefined`, and that's why you're having the error that says:

> Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

One simple way to work around it is to call the "binded" function:

> Just notice that you will need to import "TextField" component, in order to execute "find" correctly

```js
import TextField from '../path/to/TextField.jsx';

it('handles change', () => {
    const _wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage />);

    _wrapper.find(TextField).simulate('change', {
        target: {
            name: 'username',
            value: 'username',
        },
    });

    expect(_wrapper.state().username).to.equal('username');
});
```

This way, the `simulate('change')` will call `onChange` with the parameters passed. In this case, `onChange` will call `handleChange`, this time with `this` "binded" correctly.